# Windows .exe file association broken - every program (incl cmd, regedit, notepad, taskmgr) launches Excel - Not a dup

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, file-association

I have already read all the SU posts on repairing a broken .EXE file association, and also read [the Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/running-exe-starts-another-program).

All of these make the assumption that you can still launch certain programs, like cmd.exe, Notepad, Regedit or taskmgr.  On my system I cannot launch ANY .exe directly (some file associations still work), they all launch Excel and attempt to open the .exe file in Excel.

This all started when I added a file association for .tsv (tab-separated values) pointing to Excel.  Every icon for an executable in my taskbar or desktop changed to the Excel icon.

In my case I (thought I) was lucky because I had an open text editor and was able to create the .reg file described in [the Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/running-exe-starts-another-program).

The .reg file merged without errors. However, after rebooting what I saw was an open Excel with many, many popups including messages like

```
The file format and extension of 'SystemPropertiesProtection.exe' don't match.
The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it.
```

Or

```
Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern.
Warning: The digital signature is valid but the signature is from a publisher whom you have not yet chosen to trust
File Path: C:\Program Files\TechSmith\Snagit 2021\SnagitEditor.exe
```

Essentially one popup for every startup program.

Now when I attempt to execute ANY program (with a couple of exceptions, below) I get the same behavior -- Excel launches and complains about the input file.

There are a few exceptions:

- I cannot run Firefox directly.  However, I run the Ubiquiti Unifi controller for my Wifi LAN.  That program did start, and it has a button to open the Wifi dashboard in a browser.  Clicking on that button started Firefox correctly.
- My background 1Password app started at boot.
- Sysinternals Process Explorer started at boot.
- It seems a few file associations do not depend on the .exe association to launch their programs.

  - .txt -> TextPad
  - .pdf -> Acrobat Reader

Process Explorer has a File/Run... option, but attempting to use it to launch anything just launches Excel.

Attempting to launch Taskmgr.exe via Ctrl-Shift-ESC, or Ctrl+Alt+Del and selecting Task Manager just launches Excel.

I booted into the recovery command line and examined the registry hive for my user.  The key given in the Microsoft document (`FileExts`) does not exist.  The CLASSES registry tree entry for `.exe` doesn't look unusual.  It appears file associations may no longer be stored in the registry.

Is there any user-accessible way to launch a program in Windows 10 that executes the program directly instead of going through file associations?  Can anyone suggest how to open regedit.exe without going through file associations?

Comment: Is the Explorer Shell runnig? Taskbar? Icons on the Desktop?

Comment: Yes.  System appears normal except all executable icons are now Excel and any attempt to directly launch a .exe launches Excel instead.  Existing file associations can be used to launch some programs but every method for directly launching a .exe launches Excel.

Comment: Let me guess.. you used a third party file browser.. (like total commander).. what a mess to clean up.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas No, no 3rd party browser here.

Comment: Then I can't imagine how the exe file type got screwed up.  Explorer will not allow exe associations to be reassigned.  I guess you found a bug in the thing Microsoft has guarded since Windows 95.

Comment: I'm making progress... I figured out how to get an elevated command prompt (create a .bat file containing `start cmd.exe`) and run that as admin.  So far I've found that _something_ royally screwed with the file association for `.exe`, but I should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this.

The key was that I could open any program, but only via a file association, not directly.  So I finally realized I could create a .bat file containing `start cmd.exe` and launch THAT (as Administrator) from its desktop icon, giving me an elevated command prompt.

From there I could launch regedit, and what I found clearly hints at a huge bug in association management.

I created the `.tsv->Excel` association yesterday, as I was dealing with a bunch of tab-separated-value files.  I used the "Open With" context menu item from a `.tsv` file on the desktop and chose Excel from the list of candidates.

When I did that, windows created registry keys:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv_auto_file]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv_auto_file\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv_auto_file\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tsv]
@=".tsv_auto_file"
"PerceivedType"="text"
```

That looks normal.  But for some unknown reason, it also changed the association for `.exe`

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@=".tsv_auto_file"
"ContentType"="application/x-msdownload"
```

Huh??????

This was easy to fix by searching for .exe associations that had a default value of ".tsv_auto_file" and changing them back to "exefile".  In my particular instance the keys I had to reset were

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.exe]
@="exefile"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithProgids]
"exefile"=hex:
```

I also deleted the .tsv/.tsv_auto_file association for good measure as I no longer need it.  After rebooting, my system is back to behaving normally.

Comment: +1 this fixed the issue for me too. I ended up only having one broken key ([HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]) and resetting that back to exefile and rebooting fixed the issue. What a bizarre bug! My situation was the same as yours completely; changed the file associate for .tsv files to use Excel and boom, .exe files would only open Excel. Crazy that this issue still exists in 2023.

Comment: I had the same issue but my user account was not an administrator. I had to login into an admin account, and load my user's registry with "reg load HKU\MYSUSER C:\Users\MYUSER" and  "reg load HKU\MYUSER_Classes C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat"

Answer (score 2):

OK, if you can creaete & merge `.reg` files, do so with the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Launch\Command]
@="\"%1\""
```

Then navigate to 'C:\Windwows\Regedit.exe"  ( via a **TextPad** dialog if you can't open an **Explorer** window ), right-click & select **`Launch`**.

If that's successful, first check this key:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe
```

If a subkey named **`UserChoice`** exists, delete it. Then check the associations under **HKCR**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile]
@="Application"
"EditFlags"=hex:38,07,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,35,00,36,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
@="{470C0EBD-5D73-4d58-9CED-E91E22E23282}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page]
@="{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}"
```

Comment: `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe` -- There is no `FileExts` key under `Explorer`.

Comment: Attempting to run regedit from within TextPad just says "This program requires elevation".

Comment: I figured out how to get an elevated command prompt (create a `.bat` file containing `start cmd.exe`) and run that as admin. So far I've found that _something_ royally screwed with the file association for .exe, but I fixing it should be relatively easy.

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me.  i did the .bat file trick open up cmd.exe.  ran as admin..

tried to restore first but had no restore points. typeing rstrui.exe in cmd.

so now i did type "systemreset --factoryreset" > enter in cmd > selected keep my files.. just reset windows.  It's a pain since it uninstalled all my apps but it got windows working agian.

Comment: It’s totally unnecessary to reinstall or even Reset Windows to resolve the problem that was described in the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159262)